# Wso2 Scim extentinon datatype error

Tags: ldap, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

So i am extending Scim Api for Wso2. When i create an extension using a datatype `string` all the extensions work correctly. However in my Ldap i have a lot of other custom attributes and attributes that just use other datatype than `string` like `operational` or `Telephone Number`.

I tried to change the datatype value for one of the extended attributes but when requesting that attribute through Scim Api, it just leads me to a 500 error.

This is an example of the scim extension configuration

```
[{
"attributeURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0:enterprise.homePhone",
"attributeName":"homePhone",
"dataType":"Telephone Number",
"multiValued":"false",
"multiValuedAttributeChildName":"null",
"description":"The User's phone",
"schemaURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0",
"readOnly":"false",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"subAttributes":"null"
},

{
"attributeURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0:enterprise.shareDirectory",
"attributeName":"shareDirectory",
"dataType":"string",
"multiValued":"false",
"multiValuedAttributeChildName":"null",
"description":"The User's share dir",
"schemaURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0",
"readOnly":"false",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"subAttributes":"null"
},

{
"attributeURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0",
"attributeName":"enterprise",
"dataType":"null",
"multiValued":"false",
"multiValuedAttributeChildName":"null",
"description":"SCIM wso2 User Schema Extension",
"schemaURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0",
"readOnly":"false",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"subAttributes":"homePhone shareDirectory"
}]
```

How can i use these attributes in my Scim Api? Do i need some special configuration?

Comment: Please show that code that leads to a 500 error.

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure which internal part of Wso2 causes this issue

Answer (score 0):

There a set of data types which are supported by SCIM. So you have to map data types in your userstore for these.

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
| SCIM Data | SCIM Schema | JSON Type                               |
| Type      | "type"      |                                         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
| String    | "string"    | String per Section 7 of [RFC7159]       |
|           |             |                                         |
| Boolean   | "boolean"   | Value per Section 3 of [RFC7159]        |
|           |             |                                         |
| Decimal   | "decimal"   | Number per Section 6 of [RFC7159]       |
|           |             |                                         |
| Integer   | "integer"   | Number per Section 6 of [RFC7159]       |
|           |             |                                         |
| DateTime  | "dateTime"  | String per Section 7 of [RFC7159]       |
|           |             |                                         |
| Binary    | "binary"    | Binary value base64 encoded per Section |
|           |             | 4 of [RFC4648], or with URL and         |
|           |             | filename safe alphabet URL per Section  |
|           |             | 5 of [RFC4648] that is passed as a JSON |
|           |             | string per Section 7 of [RFC7159]       |
|           |             |                                         |
| Reference | "reference" | String per Section 7 of [RFC7159]       |
|           |             |                                         |
| Complex   | "complex"   | Object per Section 4 of [RFC7159]       |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-2.3